# How to create a var in an if statement with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I've a ForEach loop in my  `var body: some View`     but the var isn't recognized after the if loop. Is there a way to fix this?

I've tried to remove the if loop and set it above the body item. But then I get some error that te isOldDate var is used before Self is available.

```
if self.Bol{
  let OldDateType = self.OldDate.asDate
}else{
  var OldDateType = isNewDay
}
var isOldDate = (OldDateType, formatter: ContentView.self.Day)
```

The expected result is that  `var isOldDate` should be recognized

[image: Image with error message]

Comment: Theres a few issues with this. First of all, your constants and variables should utilize camelcase and have its first character lowercase:  `let OldDateType = self.OldDate.asDate` should be `let oldDateType = self.OldDate.asDate` and `var OldDateType = isNewDay` should be `var oldDateType = isNewDay`, though these wouldn't be causing the issue. Check out naming conventions with swift https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write the `if/else` as

```
let oldDateType = self.Bol ? self.OldDate.asDate : isNewDay
```

Comment: Sadly, it gives some errors: "Cannot use optional chaning on non-optional value of type 'Bool'" and "Consecutive statements on a lin em us be seperated by ';'"

Comment: @Ruben, Sorry that was a typo. A space was missing before the ?, see updated answer

Comment: Yeah I see, and yes the way of writing works, but the error still exists: "Use of unresolved identifier 'OldDateType'"

Comment: You must be writing that wrong then because `oldDateType` is the one @joakim created. You can’t use it until after creation. It is also a lowercase first letter

Comment: Whoops indeed, thanks. Just a short other question then. Because the if statement was to protect the loop from doing twice the samen. Thats impossible with this type because you always need the "else" statement. Is there a way to change that? like another binary operator?

Comment: @Ruben Do you need this line to be inside the loop or can you move it outside? It's hard to know without seeing all the code.

Comment: Everything I place outside the loop results in an error. Thats because it's inside a List element.